# What's wrong with my code in calculating fps?

Tags: javascript, function, frame-rate

I was making my own version of Flappy Bird & was trying to add a fps calculator.

So this is very simple & even stackoverflow already has an answer explaining how to calculate fps. Everything was Ok until I moved the calculations involved
in a separate function to keep my animate loop clear.
Here goes my code:

```
var lastLoop = new Date();

function frameRate() {
    var newLoop = new Date();
    return Math.floor(1000 / (newLoop - lastLoop));
    lastLoop = newLoop;
}


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if (!hits) {
        //game loop

        frameRate.innerHTML = `Frame rate: ${frameRate()}`;
    }
}
```

Result is fps starting with 3 or 4 then finally decreasing to 0. What's wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return` will immediately terminate the function and give you the value supplied as part of the expression. So you do not reach the last line of that function.

Comment: Yeah, your code snippet is all kinds of weird, mister -- `frameRate` is supposed to be a DOM element? Because you define a function called `frameRate`. Also, where is `hits` defined?

Comment: @amn I wouldn't worry about `hits` - it's a snippet cut down for clarity. But I do agree with `frameRate` being a problem.

Comment: Very sorry, i was not using frameRate as DOM Element but when posting my code i changed just the DOM Element name (because it was a bit weird) & didn't noticed that i have already declared one!

Comment: Thanks vlaz, You pointed out right but I can't move `lastLoop = newLoop` line before `return` statement. What else I can do?

Comment: `var result = Math.floor(1000 / (newLoop - lastLoop));` then just put `return result` in the end.

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Why? Well Windows